# Why some videos can be played in firefox but some cant?

Tags: firefox, video

So I have this .mp4 video

[image]

and when I open it in firefox its get played

but also I have this video

[image]

and it does not wont to be played in firefox and I cant get it why.
I was thinking that due to H.264 High Profile but its not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does not support mkv (matroska) files apparently.

Your second file has the *extension* mp4, but according to your screenshot it is a matroska mkv file.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422891

You can remulitplex mkv into mp4 without transcoding using `ffmpeg` and the `-c:v copy -c:a copy` options. There are a [lot of other programs that can remux as well.](https://www.google.com/search?q=remux%20mkv%20to%20mp4&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Remulitplexing will simply change the container without reencoding the file.

If it still doesn't play then there is something about the video or audio format. If it *does* play when remuxed then it is mkv support that is missing.